# Is safe call qWarning("%s", qUtf8Printable(key));

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, segment, fault

The [Qt manu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qUtf8Printable) said **The char pointer will be invalid after the statement in which `qUtf8Printable()` is used. This is because the array returned by `QString::toUtf8()` will fall out of scope.**

So does `qUtf8Printable(key)` will fall out of scope when call `qWarning("%s", Utf8Printable(key));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is safe. Temporary values used as argument survive until the end of the function call.